# Load Balancing: What is the smallest possible (i.e. tight) approximation ratio of greedy scheduling algorithm, under a set of conditions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

For the Load-Balancing problem:

Given that number of machines are exactly $m$, and arbitrary number of jobs $n$, such that the processing time of each job $t_j$ satisfies the following ($T_{min} \le t_j \le T_{max}$), and the total processing time for all jobs is $\ \ G=\sum^{n}_{j=1}t_j \ \ $ **at least**:  What is the smallest possible (i.e. tight) approximation ratio?

Based on the assumption that we are using greedy algorithm - Is it possible to derive tight approximation ratio that parameterized by $m$, $T_{min}$, $T_{max}$, and $G$?

---

I know that the approximation ratio $2 - \frac{1}{m}$ is proved to be tight for the greedy scheduling algorithm.

---

[A complete example of the above question (statements)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y7t4.png)

I just rephrased the question a bit as I do not interested answering this specific question, however I need a sort of tips helps solving similar ones. Any help is definitely appreciated.